# Efficient way to get modulo for large number (e.g., find x for 100 mod x =1)

Tags: algorithm, encryption, time-complexity, complexity-theory, modulo

Alice has a integer `x0` which she doesn't want Bob to know. Bob knows a very large integer `y` and also knows that `y mod x0 = 1`. So now Bob can solve the equation `y mod x = 1` to get different `x` to see which one is correct (Bob can verify the correctness of the obtained `x`). Is it difficult for Bob to get `x0`? Are there any efficient way for him? One way I can think of is try and error as below but I guess it's low-efficient and hence is difficult to get real `x0`. Thank you!

Example: Bob wants to get `x` for `100 mod x = 1`. Possible `x` are `3, 9, 11, 33, 99`. Bob can verify the value. Assume the verification is fast. The true value that Alice has is `33`. How difficult it is to get this `33`?

```
for i in range(2, y):
    if (y-1)%i == 0:
        x = (y-1)/i
        verify(x) // assume that verification is fast
            if verification succeeds:
                break
            else:
                continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Why are 9 and 99 not also possible x-values?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Added.

Comment: Given `100 mod x = 1`, possible values of `x` are the divisors of 99. To find the divisors of 99 start by finding the prime factorization of 99. In the general case `y mod x = 1`, when `y` is a very large number, the problem is difficult because it's difficult to factor very large numbers. At least that's the assumption being made in current  (year 2022) encryption schemes.

Comment: "very large,... trial and error, ... efficient..." these are too vague to get very useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way to solve this would imply an efficient integer factorization algorithm: to factor N, choose y=N+1, and implement `verify(x)` such that it reports True only if x is a non-trivial factor of N (which is easy), then the algorithm to recover x0 will find a non-trivial factor of N. So it is unlikely that there will be a very efficient algorithm to do this.

But it also works the other way around: we need only generate the divisors of y-1 and `verify` them, not all possible numbers, and factoring y-1 and then generating the divisors from the factors is in many cases more efficient than brute-force. Even though factoring integers is difficult<sup>[proof needed]</sup>, we have algorithms to do it that are better than brute-force, especially if the number contains small factors or repeated factors.

For example, factoring 2<sup>40</sup>*3<sup>10</sup> is easy, and then listing the divisors is easy and there aren't too many of them (451 divisors), while a brute-force approach would take an unreasonable amount of time. In general we can easily factor any 64-bit number at least.

Comment: Thanks @harold. The `y` here is much larger than 64-bit number, e.g., 100 digits or even larger. So based on the discussions in this question, in general this would be a super-hard problem right?

Comment: @Howie it's hard but I'd say "moderately hard", integer factorization is (at the same size of number) a lot easier than problems that require brute-force. For example RSA-250 (829 bit) has been factored (using significant computing resources), but we can't brute force even a 128-bit problem, which is over 6 times as small.

Comment: @Howie note that this problem is only hard if Alice gets to choose y, and she knows how to choose a hard one.

Comment: Thanks @MattTimmermans. What's the property of being a hard one then?

Comment: @Howie y-1 needs to be the product of two strong primes.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime  If Alice had to do this in real life, she'd generate an RSA key and add 1 to the modulus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)